# how do i store a gemfile within my local directory ( for GIT V.C. ) running RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubygems

i was told that using config.gem alongside :path => "path/to/dir" would work.

on server restart though environment.rb does not pull the gem im pointing at.

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I did not understand the question at all. Can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: This question is not very clear. What version of Rails are you using? Are you not using bundler?

Comment: rails 2.3.8 .. running bundler as of a few days back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SO it seems running bundler was the way to go.

in console:
    gem install bundle

then

```
gem list
```

copy those gems and format them like this: http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html. Then place them in Gemfile (home dir)

NOW for the LOCAL gem ( which i have stored in project/local_gems/thin-1.2.10 ) i placed this in the Gemfile

```
gem "thin", :path => "local_gems/thin-1.2.10/"
```

next:

```
bundle install
```

NOW... heres the tricky bit.. when running 'thin' as you web server its necessary to run thin commands within the bundled environment SO:

```
bundle exec thin start
```

and there you have it ! Running a ' thin ' web server on rails 2.3.8 using bundler!

Its is worthwhile to note that you WILL NOT see updates to you local gem file until:
- you stopped the server ( ctrl + c ) 
- saved all files associated with that gem,
 
- redo 'bundle install' 
- THEN run server again to see changes

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using rvm, and the rvm version you want to be using, when you are installing your gem? You might be trying to install the gem using your system ruby. If all that is the case, then you might want to set your default rvm version to be the one you want to use. Then you will always get the gems into that rvm version.